# Azure SqlExceptions

Tags: sql, exception, azure, sqlbulkcopy

I have a program that uploads about 1gb of data to a SQL Azure Database.
I use a SqlBulkCopy to upload this data. I upload about 8,000,000 entities, on average 32,000 entities at a time, with a maximum of about 1,200,000 in one time.

I am receiving a lot of SqlExceptions, with error code 4815.

At first I thought this may be due to me uploading too many at a time and Azure throttling my connection or employing ddos defense, but I allowed mhy program to only submit 25,000 entities with each SqlBulkCopy, and I got even more errors! A lot more!

Comment: An exact duplicate of this post: [sql-azure-more-intermittent-timeouts](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11147490/sql-azure-more-intermittent-timeouts).  See also this link: http://our.umbraco.org/forum/core/general/27179-SQL-Azure-connectivity-issues

Comment: @paulsm4 Different exceptions. He's using ASP.net mine is a WPF application, and he's not uploading 1gb of data... 

Besides I have already done what they suggest - to retry submissions and I still get these error messages.

Comment: Error 4815 looks like a log write IO delay exception.  See the following link for more details http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ff394106.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have had good results using BCP to move large amounts of data into SQL Azure. The SQL Azure migration wizard uses this approach behind the scenes. This blog post is a bit dated, but the concepts are sound when it comes to importing a lot of data:
[Brute Force Migration of Existing SQL Server Databases to SQL Azure](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rdoherty/archive/2010/09/07/brute-force-migration-of-existing-sql-server-databases-to-sql-azure.aspx)

Question did not specify source of the data, so obviously this will not work for you if you are not importing from another database.

Comment: Isn't that what I did? I used SqlBulkCopy which is the CLR wrapper for a database BulkCopy, no?
I am uploading from files on my computer, however, since I have the parsing code and UI and everything done already I could change it so it creates a local DB (.mdf), and then possibly upload that to Azure? or to an instance of SQL Server and then do a BCP?

Comment: My understanding is that SqlBulkCopy utilizes its connection much less efficiently. (read slow:) ) http://www.sqlteam.com/forums/topic.asp?TOPIC_ID=112718 I have only used BCP though and not SqlBulkCopy, so an argument could be made that the speed comparison is hearsay :)

Comment: If you are parsing large text files and placing the content into a db, I am wondering how you are dealing with failed transactions. Do you have to fail the entire file upload? Maybe a more granular approach could work. You can save off items that failed import into an "exception table" for manual analysis.

Comment: What about something like:
https://gist.github.com/3353088

Although I don't think this will work, because Azure supposedly does not allow Bulk Insert?
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee336253.aspx

Comment: You are right that there is not bulk insert today. But, that gist gives me an idea. What about a format file with BCP. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191516.aspx

Comment: I have definitely considered BCP,
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlazure/archive/2010/05/21/10014019.aspx
the thing holding me back is that most places say it's not a good way to go for users with a lot of data:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlcat/archive/2010/07/30/loading-data-to-sql-azure-the-fast-way.aspx
So far I'm thinking of either:
A. Using BCP
B. Loading the data to a SqlLocalDB and using Azure Sync

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I got a 4815 when the data I was sending in one of the fields was larger than the field size in the table definition... sending 13 characters into a VARCHAR(11).

Comment: I run into exactly this thing. Thanks for saving me a lot of time! :-)